# Spec'ing power supply to replace a battery pack in a DIY project?

Tags: power-supply, batteries

I am attempting a DIY hack that involves (among other tweaks) replacing a battery pack with a PoE power supply. The battery pack in question uses 8 1.5v D-cells in a series-parallel configuration that produces 6v.

How do I go about figuring out how many amps my power supply will need to support? The device in question is an LED lantern, and the only likely-looking spec I can find is the marketing claim that 8 alkaline D-cells will last 32 hours on the high setting.

Also, am I correct in my vague understanding that amperage is generally a *capacity*, and thus more amperage is generally not harmful? Whereas too little amperage will result in a voltage drop? (I did study basic electronics in the military, but that was a very long time ago…)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Measure it. If you already have the device you want to know about, wire an [ammeter](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ammeter) in series with the existing batteries and find out the peak current needed.

Most multimeters have an inbuilt ammeter.

[Here's a good guide](http://www.allaboutcircuits.com/vol_6/chpt_2/4.html).

Yes, the amperage rating of a power supply is the maximum current it can safely supply for the given voltage. Over-speccing your power supply should not cause a problem so long as you don't short it.